# Prove that $Y_n = X_n−E[X_n]$ is a martingale.

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a process with independent increments. We define $Y_n = X_n−E[X_n]$. Prove that $\{Y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a martingale with respect to $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.

I am trying to prove that: $E[Y_{n+1}|X_0,\ldots,X_{n}] = X_n$ then
\begin{align}
E[Y_{n+1}|X_0,\ldots,X_{n}] &= E[X_{n+1}-E[X_{n+1}]|X_0,\ldots,X_{n}]\\
&=E[X_{n+1}|X_0,\ldots,X_n] - E[X_{n+1}]\\ 
&=E[X_{n+1}-X_n +X_n|X_0,\ldots,X_n] - E[X_{n+1}]\\ 
&= E[X_{n+1}-X_n|X_0,\ldots,X_n] + E[X_{n}|X_0,\ldots,X_n]- E[X_{n+1}]\\
&= E[X_{n+1}-X_n] + X_n -E[X_{n+1}]\\
&= Y_n
\end{align}
The procedure correct? and why is $E[X_{n}|X_0,\ldots,X_n] = X_n$ true?

Comment: $E[X_n|X_0,...,X_n] = X_n$ is true because $X_n$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(X_0,...,X_n)$.  This property is sometimes called "taking out what is known."